# Access 2007 Update Table with values from form and another table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am trying to update a single table with data from an Access form and a value from another table. For example:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) SELECT '" & Me.txtBox1.Value & "'," & tableName2.ID"
```

I have never worked with Access forms prior to yesterday. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us what `strSQL` contains after you build the string.  Tell us how you're attempting to execute the statement, and what happens when you try.  If there is an error message, please show us the complete text of that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something with a SELECT FROM statement, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO
    table1
(
    col1,
    col2,
)
SELECT
    txtBox1.value,
    table2.col1
FROM
    table2
```

Obviously format the SQL to however you are coding the statement.